# error: "explicit specialization requires 'template <>'"

Tags: c++, templates

Why does this code give this error? I'm not trying to do explicit specialization. This is in Visual Studio 2012 Desktop Express.

> error C2906: 'T *testTemplate::popNoWait(int *)' : explicit
>   specialization requires 'template <>'

```
template <class T> class testTemplate
{
public:
  T *pop(int timeout_ms);
  T *popNoWait(int *remaining = NULL);
};

T *testTemplate<class T>::pop(int timeout_ms)
{
  return popNoWait();
}

T *testTemplate<class T>::popNoWait(int *remaining)
{
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you define things from a class template. You have to have the `template<>` syntax first:

```
template <class T>
T *testTemplate<T>::pop(int timeout_ms)
{
    return NULL;
}

template <class T>
T *testTemplate<T>::popNoWait(int *remaining)
{
    return NULL;
}
```